# What is the significance of square brackets in denoting the copy destination array?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have been getting familiar with how to slice and dice arrays/slices in Go (the actual task is to check if the first N bytes in a byte slice is a set of particular bytes).

So I have learnt how to copy bytes from a slice into an array:

```go
var dstArray [1]byte
srcSlice := []byte{0x00}
copy(dstArray[:], srcSlice)
```

What puzzles my though is the necessity to write `[:]` at the end of `dstArray` in the `copy` call. If I omit that I get this error:

```
first argument to copy should be slice; have [1]byte
```

First of all, why does it say "should be slice"? I provide an array instead and it works just fine (with the `[:]` bit).

And, the main question is: why does it require the `[:]` bit? What is the significance of it in this context? Could the instruction be somehow misinterpreted if we omit it? Why complicate the syntax?

Comment: "array works just fine (with the [:] bit)` - It's "the [:] bit" that makes an array a slice. This answers both your questions.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Then why does it say "should" and not "must"? Like it _prefers_ it to be a slice but could take an array or something too?

Comment: Bad choice of word by whoever wrote the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, why does it say "should be slice"?

Because this is how the API of the function is defined, go is strongly typed language, so you should provide a value of the required type.

> I provide an array instead and it works just fine (with the [:] bit).

You don't provide an array, you take an array and convert it to slice by using  [:] https://play.golang.org/p/TEih17eVWml

> why does it require the [:] bit?

This is how you get a slice from Array to conform with the Copy API

Answer (score 3):

`[:]` is the shorthand of slice expression.

According to the spec:

> For convenience, any of the indices may be omitted. A missing low
> index defaults to zero; a missing high index defaults to the length of
> the sliced operand:
>
> ```
> a[2:]  // same as a[2 : len(a)]
> a[:3] // same as a[0 : 3]
> a[:]  // same as a[0 : len(a)]
> ```

See also: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions